# JSON - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" when I try to return the `.Name` of my `JSON`.

Here's my javascript (The console.log is for testing):

```
var roomsCodes = [
    ['232','DDSB'],
    ['232','DDMB'],
    ['232','SJJB'],
    ['232','SJJS'],
];

var jsonMin = 
{
    "DDSB": {
        "Name": "Doble Estándar",
    },
    "DDMB": {
        "Name": "Doble con vista mar",
    },    
    "SJJB": {
        "Name": "Jr. Suite",
    },
    "SJJS": {
        "Name": "Jr. Suite Superior",
    },
}

for(var p = 0; p < roomsCodes.length; p++){
    if(232 == roomsCodes[p][0]){
        console.log(jsonMin.roomsCodes[p][1].Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `jsonMin.roomsCodes` ... the `jsonMin` has no property `roomsCodes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by using [] to access to the object, like this:

```js
var roomsCodes = [
  ["232", "DDSB"],
  ["232", "DDMB"],
  ["232", "SJJB"],
  ["232", "SJJS"]
];

var jsonMin = {
  DDSB: {
    Name: "Doble Estándar"
  },
  DDMB: {
    Name: "Doble con vista mar"
  },
  SJJB: {
    Name: "Jr. Suite"
  },
  SJJS: {
    Name: "Jr. Suite Superior"
  }
};

for (var p = 0; p < roomsCodes.length; ++p) {
  if (232 == roomsCodes[p][0]) {
    console.log(jsonMin[roomsCodes[p][1]].Name);
  }
}
```

When you want to access to a property using a dynamic variable you need to use square brackets otherwise you can use the dot.

Comment: I upvoted but I think you should take the chance to add a reference to MDN on how to access object properties (dot operator vs [])

Answer (score 1):

```js
var roomsCodes = [
    ['232','DDSB'],
    ['232','DDMB'],
    ['232','SJJB'],
    ['232','SJJS'],
];

var jsonMin = 
{
    "DDSB": {
        Name: "Doble Estándar",
    },
    "DDMB": {
        Name: "Doble con vista mar",
    },    
    "SJJB": {
        Name: "Jr. Suite",
    },
   "SJJS": {
        Name: "Jr. Suite Superior",
    },
}

for(var p = 0; p < roomsCodes.length; p++){
    if(232 == roomsCodes[p][0]){
      
      const item = roomsCodes[p][1]
      
     
      
      console.log(jsonMin[item].Name)
      
    }
}
```